# How do I create virtual currency or tokens from PayPal?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I've seen many sites that offer some sort of virtual currency or tokens to their users allowing them to unlock specific features of a site.  Is this part of the PayPal API or are these home grown solutions.  I've searched google and git for open source projects but can't find any.

Has anyone had experience with this and if so any suggestions on how I can create something similar?

Comment: It's not paypal specific. Each site just stores a number somewhere for each user, and has more or less developed methods of keeping track of that number. How that's done greatly depends on the site's individual needs

Comment: @Pekka웃 and yet Paypal is useful when you want to convert the real money into the kind that doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a prepaid telephony solution that stores credit that users can buy through PayPal. What I use is a basic "Buy Now Button" and I get confirmation from payments through IPN (Instant Payment Notifications). I store credits to user accounts in the database.

Important things you have to take into account:

- Avoid processing the same payment twice. Sometimes PayPal sends you a payment notification twice.
- Make sure you only process "Completed" payments.
- Verify using the PayPal IPN that each payment you receive is from PayPal. You have PHP code samples from PayPal.
- Verify the currency of your payment

You would need to adapt your user accounts to manage balances and you will also need a separate notifications table. All in all, not so complicated. Perhaps the most complicated part is verifying payments via IPN but there ara many examples of that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that helps quite a bit!

Comment: Using just IPN is too complicated (you have do do too much additional checking). It's not indended to use it for a full payment process. Yes i know, it was state of the art a while ago (and i used it too, to make payments) but "PayPal Express" is the new way. IPN is fine for notifications but unnecessary complicated for a payment process.

Comment: Yes, express checkout is a good way too although I'm not sure it is really easier to implement with its many steps. Besides, you may need to add IPN anyway if you want to automatically things like disputes for example and the effects of those on customer's balances.